# Two dates as properties in C#

Tags: c#, properties

I want to have two simple properties: the start date and the end date. I want to put a constraint that the start date must be before the end date. The problem arises when modifying both values - they may (together!) make a new, correct pair, but at the moment of adding them, there is an error. Simple example:

```
start = 5;
end = 10;

new_start = 20;
new_end = 30;

start = new_start; // error!
end = new_end;
```

That is why I introduced the third property. The thing is - the code looks terrible (especially the .Item1, .Item2 thing).

Is there a way to do it in a better way in C#?

```
    private DateTime start;
    private DateTime end;

    public DateTime Start { get { return start; } }
    public DateTime End { get { return end; } }


    public Tuple<DateTime, DateTime> Dates
    {
        get
        {
            return new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(Start, End);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value.Item1 <= value.Item2)
            {
                start = value.Item1;
                end = value.Item2;
            }
            else
                throw new InvalidDates();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow. Lots of answers. Well, here's my take.

Create two public properties for the start and end dates, and then add a SetStartAndEndDates method that does the validation. The public properties should have private setters. Since the `SetStartAndEndDates` method throws an error if invalid dates are set, you'll want to create methods allowing you to test potential dates. To illustrate this methodology, I'll create a fictional `CalendarEvent` class:

```
public class CalendarEvent
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; private set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; private set; }

    public SetStartAndEndDates(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        if (start <= end)
        {
            StartDate = start;
            EndDate = end;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidDates();
        }
    }

    public bool IsValidEndDate(DateTime end)
    {
        return StartDate <= end;
    }

    public bool IsValidStartDate(DateTime start)
    {
        return start <= EndDate;
    }

    public bool IsValidStartAndEndDate(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        return start <= end;
    }
}
```

And to use it without throwing exceptions:

```
var event = new Event();
var start = DateTime.Now;
var end = start.AddDays(7);

if (event.IsValidStartAndEndDate(start, end))
{
    event.SetStartAndEndDates(start, end);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Well, you might think about whether it would make sense to have a type which represents a start/end combination. A sort of... [`Interval`](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/T_NodaTime_Interval.htm). (Yes, this is a not-so-subtle plug for [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org), which makes date/time handling generally better anyway. But you could create your own `Interval` struct for `DateTime` if you wanted...) Then you can have a *single* property to combine the start/end times, in a way which is guaranteed to be valid.

But if you really *want* to keep them as separate properties, I'd go with a simple setter. I wouldn't create a separate exception for this though - just use `ArgumentException`:

```
public void SetDates(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    if (end < start)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("End must be at or after start", "end");
    }
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a method to set them together:

```
public void SetDates(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    if(start >= end)
        throw new ArgumentException("start must be before end");
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a method as a setter:

```
public void SetDates(DateTime startDate, EndDate endDate)
{
    if (startDate <= endDate)
    {
        start = startDate;
        end = endDate;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidDates();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having two underlying `DateTime`, I would write a class that contains one `DateTime` for the start and one `TimeSpan` for the difference between the start and end. The setter for the start would only change the `DateTime` and the setter for the end would only change the `TimeSpan` (giving an exception if it would make the `TimeSpan` negative).

You see behaviour like this in Google calendar and Outlook's calendar already, as I recall. There changing the start time of an event changes the end time too, but keeps the duration constant.

```
public class TimeWindow
{
    private TimeSpan duration;

    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndTime
    {
        get
        {
            return this.StartTime.Add(this.duration);
        }

        set
        {
            // this will throw a ArgumentOutOfRangeException if value is smaller than StartTime
            this.duration = value.Subtract(this.StartTime);
        }
    }

    public void SetStartAndEnd(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        this.StartTime = start;
        this.EndTime = end;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, waiting for it :)

Comment: This is interesting. I personally would want a separate start and end date, but it would be nice to have a method that allows you to set the end date via a TimeSpan. It could be a perfectly valid business case to set the end date to "1 week from now", for example. You could also have the `Duration` property be a calculated property based on the start and end dates. Nice idea.

Answer (score 1):

OO encapsulation isn't always about pretty implementation, it's often about pretty interfaces that provide consistent "black box" behavior. If writing the code that "looks terrible" provides a smooth interface with behavior consistent with the design, then what's the big deal? I think the solution you have is perfectly valid to keep the internals of the class consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Take the validation checks out of the setters and add a validate method. You can then set them in any order without exception and check the final outcome once you think they are ready by calling validate.

```
private DateTime start;
private DateTime end;

public DateTime Start { get { return start; } }
public DateTime End { get { return end; } }

public void Validate()
{
    if (end.Ticks < start.Ticks)
        throw new InvalidDates();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way which is not listed in answers is to implement `ISupportInitialize` interface. Before modifying dates you call `BeginInit` method and after - `EndInit`. On `EndInit` validate dates.

```
public class SomeClass : ISupportInitialize
{
    private bool initializing;
    private DateTime start;
    private DateTime end;

    public DateTime Start
    {
        get { return start; }
        set { CheckInitializing(); start = value; }
    }

    public DateTime End
    {
        get { return end; }
        set { CheckInitializing(); end = value; }
    }

    private void CheckInitializing()
    {
        if (!initializing)
        { throw new InvalidOperationException("Can not execute this operation outside a BeginInit/EndInit block."); }
    }

    public void BeginInit()
    {
        if (initializing)
        { throw new InvalidOperationException("Can not have nested BeginInit calls on the same instance."); }

        initializing = true;
    }

    public void EndInit()
    {
        if (!initializing)
        { throw new InvalidOperationException("Can not call EndInit without a matching BeginInit call."); }

        if (start <= end)
        { throw new InvalidDates(); }

        initializing = false;
    }
}
```